# Class not able to access bean managed by Spring

Tags: spring

I have Spring configuration file where I am defining beans but somehow this bean is not accessible from one of the class in same package, though same beans are accessible from Controller class which was annotated as @Controller. I was thinking may be this class was not managed by Spring but that's not the case.
1) Configuration class

```
@Bean
public FooConsumer fooConsumer() {
    return new FooConsumer();
    }

@Bean
public Map<String, ProxyConsumer> appProxyConsumerMap() {
Map<String, ProxyConsumer> proxyConsumer = new HashMap<String, ProxyConsumer>();
    proxyConsumer.put(FOO_APP, FooConsumer());
    return proxyConsumer;
    }

@Bean
public FooEventConsumer fooEventConsumer() {
    return new FooEventConsumer();
    }
@Bean
public Map<String, FooConsumer> fooConsumerMap(){
    Map<String, FooConsumer> fooEventConsumer = new HashMap<String, FooConsumer>();
    fooEventConsumer.put(FOO_EVENT, fooEventConsumer());
        }
```

2) Controller class

```
@Resource
@Qualifier("appProxyConsumerMap")
Map<String, ProxyConsumer> appProxyConsumerMap;

//proxyApp comes as path variable
ProxyConsumer consumer = appProxyConsumerMap.get(proxyApp); 
//invoke consumer
boolean consumed = consumer.consumeEvent(eventRequest);
//here consumer is my FooConsumer class, till now all works fine.
```

3) now in FooConsumer class it tries to access Map bean named fooConsumerMap to get which event to call but somehow it returns null.

```
@Resource
@Qualifier("fooConsumerMap")
Map<String, FooConsumer> fooConsumerMap;

FooEventConsumer consumer = fooConsumerMap.get(eventType);
//Here fooConsumerMap comes as null in this class, though it comes as object in controller class , please advise.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file, construct your FooConsumer bean with the FooConsumerMap bean declared in the same configuration.

You can autowire other beans into a configuration file, but to pull together beans within the file you pass them as constructor arguments.

Note that if you call a Bean annotated method multiple times, you will surprisingly always get the same instance even if the method logic constructs a new instance.

Check documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: Thanks @Chris, Below change worked for me, please advise if you meant to do this.     
Bean
public FooConsumer fooConsumer(@Qualifier("fooConsumerMap")Map<String, ProxyConsumer > fooConsumerMap) {
    FooConsumer fooConsumer = new FooConsumer(fooConsumerMap);
    this.fooConsumer=fooConsumer;
    return fooConsumer;
    }
    
private FooConsumer fooConsumer;

Bean
public Map<String, FooConsumer> fooConsumerMap(){
    Map<String, FooConsumer> fooEventConsumer = new HashMap<String, FooConsumer>();
    fooEventConsumer.put(FOO_EVENT, fooConsumer);
        }

Comment: More like in config class - @Bean FooConsumer fooConsumer() { return new FooConsumer(fooConsumerMap()); }

Comment: And keep the rest of config class as is, and just add a constructor to your FooConsumer class that takes a Map<String, FooConsumer>

Comment: Ditch the Resource and Qualifier annotations, you are not Autowiring you are declaratively creating beans

Comment: I've added a link to Spring documentation

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your help.

Comment: It worked @Chris, somehow it's not accepting autowire in method calls in all subsequent classes and It expects everywhere I should pass dependency as constructor. I think there is something I am missing in configuration which is avoiding it to accept annotation.

Comment: Hi Shakti - what do you mean by method call? Any beans declared in the configuration class can be Autowired into other beans outside the configuration class with property or constructor Autowiring as in your controller. Also, beans defined  outside your configuration class may be  Autowired into your configuration class in the same way. For connecting up beans within the configuration class NO annotations should be used. The only annotation to use is the Bean annotation on methods that define beans.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am completely with you whatever you mentioned but somehow I am seeing a weird behavior when I fixed to pass constructor injection to get consumer class "@Bean FooConsumer fooConsumer() { return new FooConsumer(fooConsumerMap()); }" then it calls service layer class method and it's not autowiring bean in service class, it expects all of them to be injected through constructor/setter injection. I really appreciate you taking time and answering my query.

Comment: In Service layer I have multiple delegate class beans and those I am autowiring but they are coming as null, not honoring @autowire annotation, all my delegator beans are declared in configuration class and I see they are initialized on server start up, which means beans are there in Heap created by Spring container but not getting pulled by Service class.

Comment: Hi Shakti, please could you share one of those service layer classes and the latest version of Configuration - maybe just append to the end of your question - ideally don't edit the original question details else the answer won't make sense. By the way if you only have a single instance of each type you don't need to use Qualifier, just Resource or Autowired as they wire by type. If you do want to autowire by name it is easier and more consistent to just use @Resource("fooConsumer") though I doubt that is the problem

Comment: Service Layer ::                                                                                            
@Service(value = "fooLogic")
public class FooLogicImpl implements FooLogic {
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooLogicImpl.class);
 Autowired
 FooServiceDelegate fooServiceDelegate;
 Autowired
 XyzServiceDelegate xyzServiceDelegate;
 Autowired
 AbcServiceDelegate abcServiceDelegate;

Comment: It would be great to have the complete source to see in GitHub or somewhere, but when you say they are null are you hitting NullPointerException when calling a service delegate method in FooLogicImpl or they are just null when debugging? Thing is, if the Autowired annotations are correct then they must be working else you'd get an UnsatisfiedDependencyException on startup. If you are debugging in FooLogicImpl and seeing null you might be looking at a proxy rather than your actual bean

Comment: Hi Chris, This issue is resolved, I have moved my beans declaration from RootConfig to RestConfig and it worked, I am not sure why that made a difference as Bean declared RootConfig should  be available everywhere below is my web initializer.

Comment: public class FooWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {@Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  rootContext.register(RootContextConfig.class);
  rootContext.refresh();
  
  container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
  container.addListener(new SessionCounter());

Comment: AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restServletContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  restServletContext.register(RestContextConfig.class);
  DispatcherServlet restServlet = new DispatcherServlet(restServletContext);
  restServlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic restDispatcher = container.addServlet("rest-servlet", restServlet);
  restDispatcher.addMapping("/rest/*");
  restDispatcher.addMapping("/admin/*");
  restDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

Comment: Hi Shakti, you are creating multiple contexts within one application. These are each separate bean factories and cannot see beans declared in the other. I think you need to do things a bit less manually here. Let Spring create an application context for you and scan for configuration and other beans. Double check the documentation for a simple Spring web application - it shouldn't be anywhere near as complex as you are making it.